# Incompatible type requires Java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue found com.android.volly.RequestQueue

Tags: android, android-volley

```
package com.example.sejal.studentdata;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name,age,cpi;
    Button insert,show;
    TextView result;
    ReferenceQueue requestQueue;
    String insertURL="http://10.130.0.85/android/insertstudent.php";
    String showURL="http://10.130.0.85/android/showstudent.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        cpi=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.insert);
        show=(Button)findViewById(R.id.show);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    }
}
```

I am trying to build an app which inserts and retrieves student data from a database.
I get an error on this line:

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
```

I added `volley  1.0.18  jar` file.

Comment: Remove the line import import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue and add import com.android.volly.RequestQueue

Comment: try some volley examples

Comment: thanks Jens its working